# How to make GET API calls that has large JSON response in Swift 5?

Tags: ios, json, swift, rest, swiftui

I am trying to fetch the Covid 19 data of all countries and their states from [disease.sh](https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/jhucsse).

I have previously fetched json data from different APIs using this method. The response in those cases were shorter compared to this.

I have posted the codes below:

```
//  Webservice.swift

import Foundation

class Webservice {
    
    let countriesURL: String = "https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/jhucsse"
    
    func getAllCountries(completion: @escaping ([Country]?) ->()) {
        
        guard let url = URL(string: countriesURL) else {
            
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                
                print("No data in response: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error").")
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(nil)
                }
                return
            }
            
            let countries = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Country].self, from: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                countries == nil ? completion(nil) : completion(countries)
            }
        }.resume()
        
    }
    
}
```

Since, I was using MVVM design, here are my Model, ViewModel and View.

```
//  Model
//  Country.swift

import Foundation

struct Country: Decodable {
    
    var country: String
    var updatedAt: String
    var stats: Stats
    var coordinates: Coordinates
    var province: String
}

struct Stats: Decodable {
    
    var confirmed: Int
    var deaths: Int
    var recovered: Int
}

struct Coordinates: Decodable {
    
    var latitude: String
    var longitude: String
}
```

```
//  ViewModel
//  CountryListViewModel.swift

import Foundation

class CountryListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var countries = [CountryViewModel]()
    
    init() {
        fetchCountries()
    }
    
    func fetchCountries() {
        Webservice().getAllCountries() { countries in
            if let countries = countries {
                self.countries = countries.map(CountryViewModel.init)
            }
        }
    }
    
}


class CountryViewModel {
    
    var country: Country
    
    init(country: Country) {
        
        self.country = country
    }
    
    let id = UUID()
    
    var name: String {
        return self.country.country
    }
    
    var updatedAt: String {
        return self.country.updatedAt
    }
    
    var stats: Stats {
        return self.country.stats
    }
    
    var coordinates: Coordinates {
        return self.country.coordinates
    }
    
    var province: String {
        return self.country.province
    }
    
}
```

```
//  View
//  ContentView.swift


import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject private var  countryListVM = CountryListViewModel()
    
    
    var body: some View {
        List( self.countryListVM.countries, id:\.id) { country in
            Text(country.name)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

My issue is when I call the Webservice.getAllCountries() it returns nil. Could anyone look at the code and tell me what is wrong, please? Thank you!

PS: I created a mock json with fewer objects (20-30) and called Webservice.getAllCountries() in this case it returned and mapped the values. It is not working with larger JSON response. **Help!!**

Comment: What response do you get from the web service?  Do you get an error? What is the error?

Comment: Is that because you are simply returning nil when countries == 0 with your completion block?

Comment: The doc says "Data tasks send and receive data using NSData objects. Data tasks are intended for short, often interactive requests to a server" about `URLSession`.

Comment: That URL doesn't seem to return a particularly large dataset.  Don't use `try ?` - That throws away decoding errors.  Use `do/try/catch` and at least print any resulting error

Comment: Thanks for providing a great question too; all the code was there and you explained what you had tried and what was happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid using `try ?` except in situations where you really don't care about failures.  `do/try/catch` is a better approach since it will tell you *why* something failed.

Changing your code to

```
do {
    let countries = try JSONDecoder().decode([Country].self, from: data)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        completion(countries)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
    completion(nil)
}
```

Gives us an error on the console -

> Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 509", intValue: 509), CodingKeys(stringValue: "province", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected String value but found null instead.", underlyingError: nil))

which makes sense, since not all countries have provinces.  To fix this, make `province` an optional in your data model

```
struct Country: Decodable {
    
    var country: String
    var updatedAt: String
    var stats: Stats
    var coordinates: Coordinates
    var province: String?
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11, I just noticed I didn't handled the null values coming from response. Such a blunder from my side. Thanks once again, Cheers mate!